# Change Language of Facebook "Send Request" button

Tags: php, facebook

I integrate the facebook in my website which is in Danish Language, and I want to send facebook request to friends from account. Then the button after selecting friends and then pressing continue says: Send request, How to change language of button "Send Request"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to do so. The language would depend on the user's choice, not yours. So the button should be in his chosen language.